# How to add drop delegate for SKCanview using .Net MAUI handler

Tags: c#, maui, skiasharp

I want to override dropDelegate of SKCanvasview by using SKCanvasViewHandler. But i am not able to find any drop delegate for the target view. The main goal is to fetch the dropped location of drop item on SKCanvasview, otherwise i can use DropGestureRecognizer of .net Maui itself, but it does not provide any way to get the dropped location, as of i know the similar feature is available in native code like this in windows, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dragstartingeventargs.getposition?view=winrt-22621). Can anyone please help ?

Approach: 1

```
SKCanvasViewHandler.SKCanvasViewMapper.AppendToMapping("OnElementChanged", (handler, view) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("insided canvas handler Here --------------> element changed");

                    Console.WriteLine(handler?.PlatformView);
                    if (handler?.PlatformView is UIView platformUiView)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("insided canvas handler ------->{0}", platformUiView);

                        // i want to achieve something like this
                        //platformUiView.DropDelegate = new MyViewDropDelegate();
                        
                    }
                });

public class MyViewDropDelegate:UIDropInteractionDelegate
    {
        public Func<Stream, Task>? Content { get; init; }

        public override UIDropProposal SessionDidUpdate(UIDropInteraction interaction, IUIDropSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here inside SessionDidUpdate ----------> ");
            return new UIDropProposal(UIDropOperation.Copy);
        }


        public override void SessionDidEnter(UIDropInteraction interaction, IUIDropSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here inside SessionDidEnter ----------> ");
        }


        public override void SessionDidExit(UIDropInteraction interaction, IUIDropSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here inside SessionDidExit ----------> ");
        }

        public override void SessionDidEnd(UIDropInteraction interaction, IUIDropSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here inside SessionDidEnd ----------> ");
        }

        public override bool CanHandleSession(UIDropInteraction interaction, IUIDropSession session)
        {

            var dropLocation = session.LocationInView(interaction.View);
            Console.WriteLine("calling session : " + dropLocation);
            return true;
        }

        public override void PerformDrop(UIDropInteraction interaction, IUIDropSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here inside PerformDrop ----------------->");
            var dropLocation = session.LocationInView(interaction.View);
            Console.WriteLine("Dropped location : " + dropLocation);

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: The link you provided is not related to the MAUI and skiasharp. You can check [SKCanvasView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.maui.controls.skcanvasview?view=skiasharp-views-maui-2.88).